# Java Dependency Injection - Annotation based setup possible in scenario?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

I'm fiddling around with Dependency Injection in Java using simple JUnit tests and javax.inject-Annotations.

I have the following scenario: There's a "top-level"-class (SomeObject) with two dependencies (SomeObjDepA and SomeObjDepB). SomeObjDepB has a dependency to SomeObjDepA too. And this should be the same instance of SomeObjDepA as in the SomeObject-instance. But SomeObjDepA must not be a Singleton, since different SomeObj-instances shall have different instances of SomeObjDepA (and SomeObjDepB). This is where I am stuck.

To be more clear, here's some basic code without any configuration:

```java
public class SomeObject {

  @Inject
  private SomeObjDepA someObjDepA;

  @Inject
  private SomeObjDepB someObjDepB;

  public SomeObjDepA getSomeObjDepA() {
    return someObjDepA;
  }

  public SomeObjDepB getSomeObjDepB() {
    return someObjDepB;
  }
}
```

```java
public class SomeObjDepA {

}
```

```java
public class SomeObjDepB {

  @Inject
  private SomeObjDepA someObjDepA;

  public SomeObjDepA getSomeObjDepA() {
    return someObjDepA;
  }
}
```

```java
public class DependencyInjectionTest {

  @Inject
  private Provider<SomeObject> someObjProvider;

  @Test
  public void instancesTest() {
    final SomeObject someObjInst1 = this.someObjProvider.get();
    final SomeObject someObjInst2 = this.someObjProvider.get();

    Assertions.assertNotEquals(someObjInst1, someObjInst2);
    Assertions.assertNotEquals(someObjInst1.getSomeObjDepA(), someObjInst2.getSomeObjDepA());
    Assertions.assertNotEquals(someObjInst1.getSomeObjDepB(), someObjInst2.getSomeObjDepB());
    Assertions.assertEquals(someObjInst1.getSomeObjDepA(), someObjInst1.getSomeObjDepB().getSomeObjDepA());
    Assertions.assertEquals(someObjInst2.getSomeObjDepA(), someObjInst2.getSomeObjDepB().getSomeObjDepA());
  }
}
```

Question: How to setup dependency injection to build up a scenario like this? I am looking for a annotation or Java based configuration (if possible)

I am currently using CDI 2.0 (Weld 3.1.5), and JUnit 5 for testing. I prefer a solution using CDI, but any other solution using Spring, Guice, etc. would be nice to.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: If applicable, you can use `@ApplicationScoped` on `SomeObjDepA` to reuse the same instance for the application.

Comment: Thanks Glains, but this will not work, since SomeObject instances should have different instances of SomeObjDepA as their dependencies.

Comment: Does SomeObject.class always have a valid instance of SomeObjDepA.class and SomeObjDepB.class? If so, cant you leave out the direct dependency for SomeObject class on SomeObjDepA and access it trough the dependency SomeObjDepB.

Comment: Yes, if I change public SomeObjDepA getSomeObjDepA() on SomeObject to return this.someObjDepB.getSomeObjDepA() instead of its local field this.someObjDepA, all assertions are true. It would be a solution for this scenario. Thank you! But this is not "real" DI in my opion. If I need a instance of some object as a dependency, I would like to get it automatically by having it injected without the need to know where it is injected as well.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're looking for, you want to make use of *scopes* and/or *qualifiers*.

You can think of a scope as a lifespan.  If you don't specify a scope (you don't anywhere above), then the default scope is "create a new one whenever one is called for", which is known as *dependent scope*.  (This is because the thing being injected's lifespan is *dependent* on the thing that is housing it.)

As @Glains points out above, `@ApplicationScoped` is one way of indicating that a bean should be in "application scope", which is basically singleton scope with extra goodies.  So you can put that on any class that meets the requirements to indicate that its lifespan should be that of the application as a whole.

Next, you talk about distinguishing between two otherwise indistinguishable occurrences of a given object, both of which might be singletons (`SomeObjDepA`).  *Qualifiers* let you do this.

Let's say that you have a [producer method](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/3.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-3.0.html#declaring_producer_method) that makes a "yellow" `SomeObjDepA` and another one that makes a "red" `SomeObjDepA`.  To do this in CDI, you'll need [qualifier annotations](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/3.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-3.0.html#qualifiers) that express the "red" and "yellow" bits.  Then apply them at the site of production.  For example:

```java
@ApplicationScoped // producer methods need to be "housed" in a bean
public class Host {

  @Produces
  @Red // you define this annotation following the spec's rules for qualifier annotations
  @ApplicationScoped // ...or whatever scope is called for
  public SomeDepA produceRedDepA() {
    return new SomeDepA();
  }

  @Produces
  @Yellow // you define this annotation following the spec's rules for qualifier annotations
  @ApplicationScoped // ...or whatever scope is called for
  public SomeDepA produceYellowDepA() {
    return new SomeDepA();
  }

}
```

Here we have two producer methods that will be called by the container appropriately and will "satisfy" relevant injection points elsewhere.  For example, in `SomeObject`, you might have:

```java
@Inject
@Red
private SomeDepA red;

@Inject
@Yellow
private SomeDepA yellow;
```